# Link to website in php

Tags: php, href

I am new to php and i have a tiny problem. I have some client website in my database and i retrieve them on page and i want if any one click on them they would go directly on that website home page but its getting tedious for me...

for example....i retrieve www.gooogle.com as

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['web']; ?>">go to home</a>
```

and when i clicked on go to home it is showing page not found and the path is:
localhost/myweb/www.google.com.

I dont know how to resolve it help if someone know about it, thanks in advance.

Comment: @sudhakar, Even www.gooogle.com redirects to google.com

Comment: If I were you, I will save the protocol together with the domain in database, such as `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $row['web']; ?>"> home Page</a>
```

Comment: offff....i was using http:://, but any way thanks y problem solved... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `http://` before the url otherwise the link will try to go relative from where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Do http://www.google.com

Without the http:// your client thinks www.google.com is a directory on the given domain.

So its not about PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://".$row['web']; ?>">go to home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<a href="//<?php echo $row['web']; ?>">go to home</a>
```

Comment: This redirects to `file://` on my Firefox on Ubuntu. I'd put `http://` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

for external links (links that refers to a external site) , you should use `http://` at the first of href .